# Как сделать так, чтобы поле было включено в две разные формы?

Tags: html, html-form

```
<input name="toPutIntoTwoForms"/>

<form action="firstAction" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<form action="secondAction" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Нужно это потому, что мне нужно получить значение `input'а` на сервере при нажатии любой из кнопок.

Comment: может сделать всё в одной большой форме и в ней делать нужные input? для каждого input можно сделать name и на сервере определять что куда было тыкнуто

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Дело в том, что `action'ы` у форм разные.

Comment: Может тогда просто input этот в каждую форму тогда засунуть?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Тогда придется 2 `input'а` создавать. Или вы имеете ввиду вариант с вложением форм?

Comment: нет, два `input`

Comment: @МихаилКамахин У меня система банов. Логин, кнопка "показать баны"(при получении добавляются кнопки doUnactive/doActive) и "добавить бан"(fromDate, toDate, forever). Логин будет странновато дублировать